# Spellcheck is not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, spell-checking, spelling

I'm trying to use this markdown editor https://simplemde.com/, but in Chrome (other browsers as well) auto spell check is not working inside the editor area.

I have tried to add spell check and content editable inside  and  elements (which is used for edit), but it is still not working.

Does anybody know, how to enable spell check in this case?

I know that guys have their own spell checker instrument, but it supports only English language.

Comment: It works for me for the 'Hidden toolbar and status bar' Editor only. Maybe there is a js config your missing, like spellcheck = true or something.

Comment: It's only they own spell checker, not the standard browser checker.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Github Page](https://github.com/sparksuite/simplemde-markdown-editor), there is a spell checking property called `spellChecker` which is by default set to true. You can try manually setting it to true for your code ( provide code so I might be able to give a direct answer to your problem ).

Example shown on github:

```
// Most options demonstrate the non-default behavior
var simplemde = new SimpleMDE({
    autofocus: true,
    autosave: {
        enabled: true,
        uniqueId: "MyUniqueID",
        delay: 1000,
    },
    blockStyles: {
        bold: "__",
        italic: "_"
    },
    element: document.getElementById("MyID"),
    forceSync: true,
    hideIcons: ["guide", "heading"],
    indentWithTabs: false,
    initialValue: "Hello world!",
    insertTexts: {
        horizontalRule: ["", "\n\n-----\n\n"],
        image: ["![](http://", ")"],
        link: ["[", "](http://)"],
        table: ["", "\n\n| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |\n| -------- | -------- | -------- |\n| Text     | Text      | Text     |\n\n"],
    },
    lineWrapping: false,
    parsingConfig: {
        allowAtxHeaderWithoutSpace: true,
        strikethrough: false,
        underscoresBreakWords: true,
    },
    placeholder: "Type here...",
    previewRender: function(plainText) {
        return customMarkdownParser(plainText); // Returns HTML from a custom parser
    },
    previewRender: function(plainText, preview) { // Async method
        setTimeout(function(){
            preview.innerHTML = customMarkdownParser(plainText);
        }, 250);

        return "Loading...";
    },
    promptURLs: true,
    renderingConfig: {
        singleLineBreaks: false,
        codeSyntaxHighlighting: true,
    },
    shortcuts: {
        drawTable: "Cmd-Alt-T"
    },
    showIcons: ["code", "table"],
    spellChecker: false,
    status: false,
    status: ["autosave", "lines", "words", "cursor"], // Optional usage
    status: ["autosave", "lines", "words", "cursor", {
        className: "keystrokes",
        defaultValue: function(el) {
            this.keystrokes = 0;
            el.innerHTML = "0 Keystrokes";
        },
        onUpdate: function(el) {
            el.innerHTML = ++this.keystrokes + " Keystrokes";
        }
    }], // Another optional usage, with a custom status bar item that counts keystrokes
    styleSelectedText: false,
    tabSize: 4,
    toolbar: false,
    toolbarTips: false,
});
```

This is what is happening here: `spellChecker: false,`. So try setting it to true, like shown in this example to your case.

Comment: It's enable their own spell checker who works only with English language. I'm looking for browser standard checker.

Comment: May be try getting a plugin and see if  that works. Like Grammerly Chrome extension or something like that.

Comment: Thanks, but again it's only English grammar :( I need Russian language support.

Comment: Try this (it supports 12 languages including Russian): https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/spell-checker-for-chrome/jfpdnkkdgghlpdgldicfgnnnkhdfhocg?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I found the place where guys switch off the spellchecker and comment this. It helps.
https://github.com/sparksuite/simplemde-markdown-editor/issues/630
Thanks for your answers.